# How to compare and extract corresponding data across CSV files?

Tags: csv, mapping

I have several csv files, some around 30mb, and I need to quickly compare some values with a set of other values and merge. Example:

```
File 1
A          B
Fail
Fail
Day
Day
Day
Night
Night
Spring
Summer
Winter
Winter
Winter
```

The second file will have something like:

```
File 1
A          B
Fail       1
Day        2
Night      3
Spring     4
Summer     5
Winter     6
```

Where col A is the var and col B represents an ID. I need to have the program check the first file against the second and return the ID so I end up with something like:

```
File 1
A          B
Fail       1
Fail       1
Day        2
Day        2
Day        2
Night      3
Night      3
Spring     4
Summer     5
Winter     6
etc
```

So wherever it can match a col exactly, it takes the ID and adds it to a col in the first document. I don't know what this process might be called, maybe ID mapping or something like that but if this is possible with some program, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm willing to try any open source solution out there and depending on the cost, I might be able to swing something that costs some money as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Excel, create a new workbook. Copy and paste the first table in `File 1` to `Sheet1`. Copy and paste the second table in `File2` to `Sheet2`.

Go back to `Sheet1` and enter the following formula into `B2` (or right beside the first element whose ID you want):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

... and drag down to end of list in `Sheet1`.

**Set-up:**

Sheet1:
[image]

Sheet2:
[image]

**Result of formula:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: +1 Just like your other answer this one is spot on. Many thanks. Tried it out and it works perfectly. Alas, because of user error when they originally input the data, I have lots of records not matching the key. Too bad I wasn't involved in the original program and I could have instituted some kind of validation to catch their errors. Thanks though, this saves a lot of time.